# Firebase Cloud Messaging. Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase cloud messaging to show push notifications. Everything worked fine on the same project some time ago. Now I'm getting `Token retrieval failed:SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error when I'm trying to retrieve token from firebase. I've already seen some solutions on stack overflow connected with facebook SDK and emulators. I'm testing on multiple real devices, none of these solutions work.

Here is my app level gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':materialrangebar')
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    api 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.12.0'
    implementation "com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:1.5.0"
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is how I'm trying to get token

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete( Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                } else {
                    requestDeviceRegistration(task.getResult().getToken());
                    Log.e(TAG, task.getResult().getToken());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the steps to [add Firebase to your project.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) Make sure your `google-services.json` is correct and you have your root-level `build.gradle` setup to include `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I already followed the steps and added firebase to my project. And as I mentioned it worked fine recently

Comment: Have you cross-referenced your google-services.json that is in your firebase console with the one in your codebase?